# How to handle a callback url in React

Tags: reactjs, api, callback, get

I am building a full-stack application, where users upload videos and the server does some manipulation and eventually informs the user if the conversion is complete.

On the front-end, I have React and close the connection, when the upload is finished. In the meantime my server does the conversion and I would like to find a way to inform my front-end that the conversion has finished. How could I do this? Maybe through using some callback url? Thank you

Comment: Something like [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)/[Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) might help you achieve this.